# How to hide cmd console when excute *.exe program compiling by Nuitka?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, nuitka

I use this command to build my program,it generate an exe file that work well.but it always starts with cmd console program when tk program is running.How to avoid that happen?

```py
python -m nuitka --mingw64 *.py
```

if I use `--windows-disable-console` command,it will generate a exe file that cannot not show tk program properly.

```py
#encoding=utf-8
import tkinter

from tinter import *
import datetime
import sys,io

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf-8')
class Example(object):
    """docstring for"""
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date
    def main_gui(self):
        parent=Tk()
        parent.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        parent.title("incomeoutcome")
        parent.mainloop()


today=datetime.date.today()
ins_bill=Example(today)
ins_bill.main_gui()
```

Comment: Instead of using ```.py```, try saving your script as ```.pyw```

Comment: It doen't work on my machine,with adding --windows-disable-console or not.Just as usual(when add disbale-console command tk gui doesn't show up.).Can you be more specific how to solve this problem,ty.

Comment: If I have an ```example.py``` with a tk script inside it, I'd save it as ```example.pyw``` so that it can be run without having the cmd console displayed

Comment: I get what pyw do,but this is not the key point I want to ask.And some examples.pyw program like class definition can't not right click pyw file to run(Is this problem also appear on your machine?),the program show above cannot run in pyw click.I mean I can run without cmd console in py or pyw file.But when compile to example.exe,it always shows the cmd consle with the program running.After I use the --windows-disable-console command,the program doesn't show up at all⑵

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the line`sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf-8')` ,and all program will be run correctly.This line of code only help show utf-8 character in emulator.